# chrome.tabs.executeScript is unreliable

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to inject content script dynamically so I'm using the documented `chrome.tabs.executeScript` method for this.

However, unlike embedded content scripts (defined in the manifest) the dynamic script runs on a random basis while I need to be sure it runs everytime.

Basically I listen for tab update events in background script and execute dynamic content script on every `"loading"` event

What I've noticed is that the behavior seems to be connected with page/script loading timing - if page loading completes before the script execution, the script won't run, otherwise it seems to work as expected.

Though this is just a guess based on the observation and if you have any other ides of what is going on here feel free to share your thoughts.

Is there any ways to ensure dynamic script executes 100% of the time despite of any circumstances?

Here is the log sequence in which script doesn't run:

```
loading: changeInfo =  {status: "loading"}
loading: start. sender.tab.id =  1454
loading: start script loading
loading: code size =  4190306  bytes
loading: changeInfo =  {status: "complete"} <- page loading completed
loading: time to execute script =  945 <- script execution completed
```

And here is the code snippet:

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function (tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    console.log("loading: changeInfo = ", changeInfo)
    if (changeInfo.status !== "loading") {
        console.log("loading: skip");
        return;
    }
    console.log("loading: start. sender.tab.id = ", tabId)

    console.log("loading: start script loading")
    var timerStart = Date.now();
    console.log("loading: code size = ", byteCount(scriptCode), " bytes")
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId,
        {
            code: scriptCode,
            runAt: "document_idle"
        }, function (response) {
            console.log("loading: time to execute script = ", Date.now() - timerStart)
            var err = chrome.runtime.lastError;
            console.log("loading: response = ", response, ", err = ", err)
        });
});
```

There are also no errors in the log

One more thing to add - if I wrap `chrome.tabs.executeScript` in `setTimeout` with something like 2000ms delay this guarantees script will **never** run which suggests timing issue.

Comment: There are no guarantees that 'loading' status will be sent to every tab. Sometimes tabs may be prerendered and they will be 'complete' when onUpdated listener is invoked. Either check for changeInfo.url or switch to webNavigation.onCommitted.

Comment: @wOxxOm thanks for your note - I'll consider this. However there is still something else to this as the issue reproduces on page refreshing - if I refresh page say 10 times the script may run only 7 times out of 10 - while I receive "loading" event every time the script still doesn't run on the guaranteed basis

Comment: Maybe it actually runs but doesn't do what you want. See if the web page devtools lists your extension in its network panel and console context selector https://puu.sh/An7VY/9757f96c74.png

Comment: @wOxxOm - well, I was thinking if that might be the case - the scrip actually adds UI elements on the page and runs some logs in the console. If it runs - it leaves it's traces in both UI and devtool console. And it unfortunately doesn't happen 100% of the time. I've also checked the console as per your screenshot - looks like it only lists the embedded content scripts defined in the manifest - no traces of the dynamic one even when it works as expected. Anyways, thanks for your input as I wasn't aware of this part of the console

Comment: @wOxxOm - here is one more thing - if I wrap chrome.tabs.executeScript in setTimeout with some delay it ensures the script never executes... which suggests the issue might be connected with timing. Is there anything that can be done about it? (I'm thinking of a dirty hack where executeScript callback will fire logic to refresh the page if the content script doesn't cancel that logic at some point in time, which means it's not executed so we'll try once again by reloading the page)

Comment: I haven't encountered such behavior. It could be a bug in Chrome. Try document_end instead of idle. Try webNavigation API events.

Comment: yep, tried document_end - doesn't make much difference. Will check webNavigation events though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, that was dumb - the problem appeared to be in the dynamic script code itself: the main logic was executed in the `onload` callback and was never run if the script loads after the `onload`:

```
window.addEventListener("load", mainLogic, false);
```

removing the callback and running `mainLogic()` directly fixed the issue.

I'll leave it here in case someone did the same mistake as I did.